# Will spray paint bleed through paint on new plaster walls?

Tags: walls, paint, plaster, spraypainting

I had kids come on the construction site and spray paint my bare plaster walls with graffiti!!!

If I paint the walls now will it bleed through the paint? Do I have to take off the plaster and start all over again? What paint can cover it and not bleed through? any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Ann

Answer (score 1):

Primer will cure a lot, and this is one of them.  I'm assuming you will be using painters, they will know how prep the walls so you will never see where it was graffiti-ed.